# ListPlot grouping by elements

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have data regional data listed by country in this form:

```
data = {{{"Reg1", "Country1", 5}, {"Reg1", "Country2", 6}}, {{"Reg2", 
     "Country3", 2}, {"Reg2", "Country4", 3}, {"Reg2", "Country5", 
     3}}};
```

I want to plot all the country values in each region on a single x-value, such as I have, in the example, two x values.

So far I can only plot as follows in which in absence of y values ListPlot assigns consecutive x values to each data point.

```
ListPlot[data[[1 ;; 2, ;; , 3]]]
```

[image]

I would like it to look like this:

[image]

My original dataset is huge so I need it to be programmed and I have more than 3 columns, I have values per country for several years which I'd like to plot on separate graphs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Table[{i, #} & /@ (data[[i, ;; , 3]]), {i, 2}] // ListPlot
```

produces what you request:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
Thread /@ Transpose[{Range[Length@data], data[[All, All, -1]]}] // ListPlot
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cords=MapIndexed[{First@#2, Last@#1} &, data, {2}]
ListPlot[coords]
```